# Jurisdiction of Texas Rangers in Louisiana?

Tags: criminal-law, new-york-state, texas, jurisdiction, legal-history

I understand that Texas Rangers are responsible for killing Bonnie& Clyde in North Louisiana.  Is it lawful for a Texas Police Agent to engage a citizen in New York City?

Answer (score 7):

Answering the question title, a Texas law enforcement officer can certainly make arrests in Louisiana these days under the right circumstances (I'm not about to look up the laws as of 1934). For starters, Louisiana law grants *any* person the authority to make an arrest when the person being arrested has committed a felony, whether or not that felony was committed in the presence of the person making the arrest. This is normally a legally risky thing to do (the arrest is illegal unless the person *actually* committed a felony, while a cop's felony arrest is legal as long as the cop had probable cause), but in this case the pair had been involved in a kidnapping and a robbery in Louisiana. Any person could have made a lawful arrest, and could have used necessary force to effect that arrest.

But suppose the gang turned out to be innocent of the Louisiana crimes. In that case, a citizen's arrest would be illegal. But the Texas lawmen weren't at the ambush alone. They were there with the parish sheriff and a deputy, who were Louisiana peace officers with the authority to make an arrest on probable cause. And under Article 219 of the Code of Criminal Procedure,

> A peace officer making a lawful arrest may call upon as many persons as he considers necessary to aid him in making the arrest.  A person thus called upon shall be considered a peace officer for such purposes.

---

Neither of these things depends on the Texas officers' status as Texas officers. There are some arrests which are legal based on that (e.g. hot pursuit), and a Texas officer has some extra powers in Louisiana based on federal law that make an arrest easier (e.g. cops in the US can carry concealed firearms nationwide without needing a CCW permit), but under normal circumstances a Texas police officer has no special authority to make an arrest in Louisiana.

However, it's not at all uncommon for police agencies in different states (or at the state and federal level) to cooperate on something, and there are ways to make it work out. With more planning, there are normally formal ways to do it instead of needing to rely on "we'll ask you for assistance" (for instance, officers could formally be appointed as deputies in the appropriate agency; this happens a lot on federal task forces, where a deputized state or local cop gets nationwide jurisdiction). If Bonnie and Clyde existed these days but the feds wanted to involve state cops, they'd just set up a federal task force, make Hamer a special deputy US marshal, and go from there.

Comment: Isn't due process (conviction or plea) required to determine a felony act?  Once a felon completes his sentence, he is still a felon; so, to say that any person has the authority to make an arrest when the person being arrested has committed a felony seems a bit too unqualified.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "seems a bit too unqualified." Can you elaborate?

Comment: I mean that is it reads, it is imprecise and inaccurate.  As written one is led to believe that anyone can arrest anyone in Louisiana (as every American adult has committed a felony in their life)

Comment: @RonRoyston First, not every American adult has committed a felony in their life, let alone one where the statute of limitations isn't up (those are a thing), and let alone one which can be the basis of a warrantless Louisiana arrest (federal offenses may or may not count, I'm not entirely clear, but crimes in other states almost certainly do not).

Comment: Second, even if most people had committed felonies, unless you can actually point to any evidence that *this* person committed a crime, then the juries hearing the lawsuit and the criminal prosecution against you are exceedingly unlikely to find in your favor (they may not even be told you might have been justified, because that often requires *some* evidence supporting it). *You* will wind up guilty of a crime; the person you arrested walks away with you owing them money.

Comment: Bernard Kerik says every adult American is a Felon, and he is right.  If you're an American adult, you've committed a felony at some point, actually several at many points.  Whether you were indicted or prosecuted is another matter.  If you don't believe him and me, you simply are not aware at the reach of State and Federal American Criminal Codes.  Former [NYPD Chief Bernard Kerik Discusses Ferguson, Police Militarization, and Clemency](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vfDZ22hTik) see end of video

Comment: @RonRoyston, a felon is a person who has been convicted of a felony, not a person who you can wildly imagine possibly being convicted of a felony given a completely corrupt legal system.

Comment: I thought it was reasonably clear from cpast's answer that you couldn't arrest someone merely because they had committed a felony at some earlier point in their life. You arrest them for a felony recently committed, for which they have not yet been brought to court. I don't know if @RonRoyston missed that point or is just looking for an excuse to mention silly theories. Regarding said silly theory: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22530/does-the-average-american-unwittingly-commit-three-felonies-a-day

Comment: @PatrickConheady I appreciate y'alls feedback yet respectfully know that legal/lawful details matter.  One is not a felon because he commits an act meetings elements of a felony statute.  One must be 1) caught doing said act, 2) indicted, and 3) subject to due process resulting in conviction or plea.  So, to say a LA resident can make an arrest using deadly force as long as subject committed a felony makes no sense to me bcs a felony takes time to precipitate.  However, I imagine there are fugitive cases that makes sense to me.

Comment: @Ron You commit a felony before you're convicted. When you stick a gun in someone's face and demand money, you just committed a felony, and can be arrested by any person in Louisiana if you did it in Louisiana. It is not limited to already-convicted fugitives. That said, unless you can credibly argue that the arrest was lawful (and "there are so many laws that he probably did something" is not going to work as an argument), no court will agree that it was a valid arrest. You will go to jail for false imprisonment and/or kidnapping.

Comment: @cpast That makes sense, certainly.  But, what about innocent until proven guilty?  "Felony" is a construct of a government and dependent on government.  For example, driving 100MPH is a felony in some US states however one is not a felon unless subject to due process and found guilty or plea.  I agree with what you are saying though - as a regular citizen it is generally not a good idea to try to arrest anyone in LA, or anywhere else.

Comment: @RonRoyston I think you're forgetting that the legality of the arrest isn't determined on the spot, and are taking "innocent until proven guilty" much further than it actually goes. If you stick a gun in someones face and order them to give you money, you have *in fact* committed robbery, whether or not you've been charged or convicted of a crime. "Innocent until proven guilty" doesn't mean "conviction magically goes back in time and makes a past action of theirs a crime." Also, the law doesn't say "you may arrest a felon," it says "you may arrest a person who has committed a felony."

Comment: However, the decision of whether or not the arrest was legal comes later, and if you're sued or prosecuted then it's up to *you* to argue that the person was, in fact, committing a felony. In any lawsuit, unless *you* can show that the person had committed a felony, you're liable for false arrest and/or assault. If you're prosecuted for the arrest the burden of proof is harder to find, but you at the very least need *some* evidence that the person had in fact committed a crime (else the jury isn't even told about citizen's arrests).

Comment: It's true that you cannot possibly know for sure whether or not a citizen's arrest is legal at the time of the arrest. This is why they're bad ideas. But after the fact, courts can look at whether or not the person in fact committed a felony (which doesn't depend on "has it been proven beyond a reasonable doubt," and it's entirely possible for one jury to find that the preponderance of the evidence is that they had committed the felony while another finds there's reasonable doubt).